# How to disable zsh substitution/autocomplete with URL and backslashes

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I am using `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh` on Ubuntu:14.04.

The shell autocompletes escape character with backslash when I paste a URL.

For example with environment variables:

```
$ wget http://{DEFAULT_IP}/index.html
It will become:
$ wget http://\{DEFAULT_IP\}/index.html
```

How can I disable this function?

Comment: Another workaround is to add quotes to the URL.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

update 2019-05-12:

new version(> 486fa10) oh-my-zsh have a configuration for this, add `DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true` before `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`:

```
DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

via: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/commit/486fa1010df847bfd8823b4492623afc7c935709

---

Original answer:

This is a bug in zsh 5.1.1 ~ 5.2(current).

The plugin `bracketed-paste-magic` did not works in the zsh versions.

The issue is here:

- https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/102
- https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/5499
- https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/commit/35517457921c095be1aa6ed948debfbe183b89ac

I suggest you disable `bracketed-paste-magic`.

Comment these code from oh-my-zsh's `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh` solve the problem:

```
if [[ $ZSH_VERSION != 5.1.1 ]]; then
  for d in $fpath; do
    if [[ -e "$d/url-quote-magic" ]]; then
      if is-at-least 5.1; then
        autoload -Uz bracketed-paste-magic
        zle -N bracketed-paste bracketed-paste-magic
      fi
      autoload -Uz url-quote-magic
      zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
      break
    fi
  done
fi
```

[via](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/102#issuecomment-178267194)

Comment: What is `bracketed-paste-magic` this plugin used for? Why the official ohmyzsh doesn't disable it.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 does not have zsh 5.1 (which introduced bracketed paste), which has been released in August 2015, thus after the question was asked.

Comment: @ErtuğrulAltınboğa It is waitting fix. https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/5499

Comment: Just fyi, I'm seeing this behaviour with zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0) too

Comment: Correction: `DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"`

Answer (score 19):

I ended up at this answer but still could not understand why pasting a URL was escaping characters like `& ? [ ]` and causing my curl commands to fail.

The culprit (for me) was iTerm2 on Mac.

To disable the behavior, go into `iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Terminal` and UNCHECK `Terminal may enable paste bracketing`.

Make sure you do this for the correct profile.

[image: iTerm2 - Disable paste bracketing]

Comment: If you use oh-my-zsh in Iterm2 you need to insert `DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true` before source oh-my-zsh.sh as described above as well otherwise you will still see the same issue.

Answer (score 11):

If the URL is not quoted, the backslashes may be necessary, that's why zsh adds them (via `url-quote-magic`). If you do not like them, then quote the URL:

```
$ wget '
```

then paste the URL and type the ending quote:

```
$ wget 'http://{DEFAULT_IP}/index.html'
```

To disable the `url-quote-magic` feature entirely:

```
zstyle ':urlglobber' url-other-schema
```

**EDIT:** As of version 5.1, zsh supports *bracketed paste* in some terminals, in which case `url-quote-magic` is no longer involved (`bracketed-paste-magic` replaces it for pastes).

Comment: How do I disabed this function in oh-my-zsh? It is a little inconvenient for me. Is any reason for zsh doing this?

Comment: @LiMingHung I've updated my answer. And zsh (actually oh-my-zsh) does this because this is what most users expect, in particular due to the & character that can be found in many URL's and thus needs to be quoted.

Comment: This zstyle command looks like only effect on logined user. If other users try to login again. It is useless. Not a system global settings. If I try to add it in zshrc, also useless.

Comment: @LiMingHung Try to add it at the end of your `.zshrc` and at the end of your `.zlogin` (both may be necessary: `.zshrc` because `.zlogin` is not always sourced, and `.zlogin` because it is sourced after `.zshrc`).

Comment: Ooops. It is also useless.

Comment: For me, backslashes are added even if I put in quotes. I tried adding the last bit of your answer to my `.zshrc` file, but it didn't work. I can't find the `.zlogin` file, unfortunately.

Comment: @SkeletonBow I suspect that the issue you see with quotes is due to something else: bracketed paste. I think that you should either disable `bracketed-paste-magic` or use `backward-extend-paste` so that `bracketed-paste-magic` can see the quote in the context. Note: I've edited my answer to mention bracketed paste, which is a new feature.

Comment: THANK YOU. The zstyle disable did the trick. Love you!!

Answer (score 4):

show my zsh version

```
echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.3
```

open misc.zsh

```
vim ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh
```

you will see the following:

```
autoload -Uz is-at-least

# *-magic is known buggy in some versions; disable if so
if [[ $DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS != true ]]; then
  for d in $fpath; do
    if [[ -e "$d/url-quote-magic" ]]; then
        if is-at-least 5.1; then
            autoload -Uz bracketed-paste-magic
            zle -N bracketed-paste bracketed-paste-magic
        fi
        autoload -Uz url-quote-magic
        zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
      break
    fi
  done
fi

## jobs
setopt long_list_jobs

env_default 'PAGER' 'less'
env_default 'LESS' '-R'

## super user alias
alias _='sudo'

## more intelligent acking for ubuntu users
if which ack-grep &> /dev/null; then
  alias afind='ack-grep -il'
else
  alias afind='ack -il'
fi

# only define LC_CTYPE if undefined
if [[ -z "$LC_CTYPE" && -z "$LC_ALL" ]]; then
    export LC_CTYPE=${LANG%%:*} # pick the first entry from LANG
fi

# recognize comments
setopt interactivecomments
```

add the following line at the top of the file

```
DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true
```