# Stop zsh from escaping characters

Tags: zsh

When typing certain symbols in zsh, it seems that zsh keeps ecaping them automatically. I've tried the solution mentioned in here [How to disable zsh substitution/autocomplete with URL and backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614613/how-to-disable-zsh-substitution-autocomplete-with-url-and-backslashes), but this must apply to an older version or something.

For example, I am trying to type:

`for i in $(cat ../targets_apps.txt); do curl http://$i; done`

but it becomes

`for i in $(cat ../targets_apps.txt); do curl http://$i\; done`

I am using version 5.2.1, according to:

```
[root:kali:]# echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.7.1
```

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Are you using `oh-my-zsh`? The linked question isn't relevant to vanilla `zsh`, as far as I know.