# Why does an encoded password not work in Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

In trying to get a Liberty container to work I'm encountering the following problem.

For a database connection I have an authData section like this in the server.xml:

```
<authData id="datasourceAuth" user="test" password="{xor}ABCD"/>
```

When I try to run the server with the password not encoded the database connection works as expected, but when the password is encoded I get this message: Connection refused (Connection refused). ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = -4,499

It looks like the password isn't being decoded when setting up the connection, but I don't understand why or if I am missing something in the configuration.

Comment: I doubt that the xor encryption does not work, I think it is just a type-o from your side. Can you compare the password, a good tool for doing this is  https://strelitzia.net/wasXORdecoder/wasXORdecoder.html ?

Comment: I think the problem might be that there are a couple of special characters in the password, I'm trying to figure it out. I already found the website you mentioned and decoding there gave the correct password.

Comment: Found the problem, it was pasting the password into iTerm2. See this link, bottom answer for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614613/how-to-disable-zsh-substitution-autocomplete-with-url-and-backslashes.

Comment: If you use a terminal emulator, make sure that your session is configured to use the same code page as your server. And remember... user ID or password fields must be in US-ASCII, otherwise make sure that the file is saved by using UTF-8 character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding of data source passwords is supported in Liberty and ought to be working.  I'll provide a more complete example aligning with the style of config you are using, as well as a reference to an official [knowledge center doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_config_dds.html) with its own example

Use the securityUtility to encode the password,

```
securityUtility encode --encoding=xor test123
```

output:

```
{xor}KzosK25tbA==
```

Configure the value on authData and use the authData on a dataSource,

```
<authData id="datasourceAuth" user="test" password="{xor}KzosK25tbA=="/>
<dataSource id="testdb" jndiName="jdbc/testdb" containerAuthDataRef="datasourceAuth">
  <jdbcDriver libraryRef="db2jcc"/>
  <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="TESTDB" serverName="localhost" portNumber="50000"/>
</dataSource>
```

The authentication data applies when using a resource reference with container authentication.

I'd recommend going back and trying all of the steps again to rule out the possibility of a typo or copy/paste error.  If it still doesn't work, then raise a case against OpenLiberty here,
https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/new/