# ZSH keeps putting backslashes in my pasted URLS

Tags: zsh

I have already tried the solution at [How to disable zsh substitution/autocomplete with URL and backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614613/how-to-disable-zsh-substitution-autocomplete-with-url-and-backslashes), but this is no longer working.

If I paste a URL, it keeps putting backslashes. Very annoying.

For example:

```
https://www.google.com?test=sample1&test2=sample3
```

will become:

```
curl -X POST "https://www.google.com\?test\=sample1\&test2\=sample3"
```

Here's the top of my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true
export ZSH=/Users/myuser/.oh-my-zsh
```

I have already tried to re-call the source, no luck. The only way I've been able to get around this is to open up a bash shell instead, which can be extremely inconvenient.

Comment: I can not reproduce it. Are you sure it is zsh doing it? What happens if you open a different subshell, for instance by typing `sh` or `dash` or `ksh`, and paste the string there.

Comment: Do the backslashes also appear if you paste the URL into between single quotes, i.e. you type `curl -X POST ''`, and then paste between the quotes? And what happens if the string to be pasted, does not look exactly like a complete URL, but is just (for instance) `sample1&test2`?

Comment: Yep! If I try with bash, it doesn't happen. It only happens in zshell. If I paste the URL in between quotes in zshell, still does the same thing. Will try shortly with a non URL

Comment: This sounds related to the `url-quote-magic` widget. Backslashes *or* double-quoting the entire URL would be correct; both is not. What happens if you disable oh-my-zsh?

Comment: If I disable `oh-my-zsh` then I can paste the URL just fine without it adding the backslashes. The only plugin that I have in the plugins directory with "url" in it is urltools

Comment: I added `DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"` to the top of my ~/.zshrc file and that fixed this issue. Can you post this as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 6):

### After search this worked for me

1. open the file `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh`
2. comment these lines below

```
if [[ $ZSH_VERSION != 5.1.1 ]]; then
  for d in $fpath; do
    if [[ -e "$d/url-quote-magic" ]]; then
      if is-at-least 5.1; then
        autoload -Uz bracketed-paste-magic
        zle -N bracketed-paste bracketed-paste-magic
      fi
      autoload -Uz url-quote-magic
      zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
      break
    fi
  done
fi
```

the final result is

```
autoload -Uz is-at-least

# *-magic is known buggy in some versions; disable if so
# if [[ $DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS != true ]]; then
#   for d in $fpath; do
#     if [[ -e "$d/url-quote-magic" ]]; then
#       if is-at-least 5.1; then
#         autoload -Uz bracketed-paste-magic
#         zle -N bracketed-paste bracketed-paste-magic
#       fi
#       autoload -Uz url-quote-magic
#       zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
#     break
#     fi
#   done
# fi

## jobs
setopt long_list_jobs

env_default 'PAGER' 'less'
env_default 'LESS' '-R'

## super user alias
alias _='sudo '

## more intelligent acking for ubuntu users
if (( $+commands[ack-grep] )); then
  alias afind='ack-grep -il'
else
  alias afind='ack -il'
fi

# recognize comments
setopt interactivecomments
```

### Relative Links

https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/5499

[How to disable zsh substitution/autocomplete with URL and backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614613)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating oh-my-zsh version.

```bash
omz update
```

If you don't want nor are unable to update the version, You maybe can uncomment it (latest code at `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh`, I didn't test it though)

```
# *-magic is known buggy in some versions; disable if so
if [[ $DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS != true ]]; then
  for d in $fpath; do
    if [[ -e "$d/url-quote-magic" ]]; then
      if is-at-least 5.1; then
        autoload -Uz bracketed-paste-magic
        zle -N bracketed-paste bracketed-paste-magic
      fi
      autoload -Uz url-quote-magic
      zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
    break
    fi
  done
fi
```